# Get file size with SharePoint 2010 REST call

Tags: 2010, rest, folder, file

Is there a way to get file size with SharePoint 2010 REST (via `_vti_bin/ListData.svc`) service?
The same question about number of items in some folder.
I don't see such fields in items corresponding to documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does **not** seem possible to retrieve File Size using SharePoint **2010** REST Interface.

But you could consider to retrieve file size from `Content-Length` header via HTTP HEAD request (without downloading a file).

JavaScript example:

```
function getFileSize(fileUrl,success) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: fileUrl,
        success : function(message,text,response){
                    var fileSize = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
                    success(fileSize);
                 }
    });            
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried HEAD request but server responds with HTTP 501. I consider SOAP instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can get file size with REST services in SharePoint 2010.

http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/26/uploading-files-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-and-rest.aspx

This link has details of using REST Service to get file size

You need to use code mentioned in above link.

Comment: Please add substantial part of the post in your answer to save it for future use.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please read my question carefully! I need SP 2010 (_vti_bin/ListData.svc) and GET file size